# How to import Magicalvoxel file into Xcode and use it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I recently came across software called Magicalvoxel. It is pretty cool if I can import some object into my Swift game project. I searched on the Internet but I could not find any good resource, though there were some how to for Unity. In doing so, should I make a game project with SceneKit or Spritekit? I am not sure about how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use File > Export > obj and import exported geometry into Xcode.
And you should use SceneKit for such 3d objects.